# Run-Time Check failure #2 MSVC debug only with utf8proc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, utf-8

I'm pretty new to c++, and this is one of my first attempts at making something relatively large/useful, so if there are any glaring errors which are not related to my question, a constructive comment would be appreciated.

For some utf-8 related operations, I'm using the C library [utf8proc](https://juliastrings.github.io/utf8proc/).

## The Problem

When building with latest MSVC 15 for a debug target, running a test program using this code (basically as simple as printing the results of this function), it yields an error saying:

> Debug Error!
>
> *[Some info about which exe file failed]*
>
> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'character' was corrupted.

Any other compiler (which I have tried) or a release target does not give this error, and instead gives correct output for whatever I throw at it.

There are a few interesting occurrences to note (these were tested with gcc):

First, the memory of `codepoint` and `character` seem to be randomly altered at times (hence the hacky mitigation of saving `codepoint` to `codepointCopy`).

Secondly, `character`, once encoded, sometimes has odd trailing characters (I assume because of uninitialised memory, however, attempts to set the memory in `character` to 0 manually by means of `memset` did not help, is there something obvious missing?), hence the hacky `.substr(0, charSize)`, which so far works fine.

## The Code

```
#include <string>

#include "../include/utf8proc.h"

std::string calculateUnicodeNormalization(const std::string &in, const std::string &mode) {
    auto pString = (const utf8proc_uint8_t*) in.c_str();

    utf8proc_uint8_t* pOutString;
    // These two functions are from c and use malloc to allocate memory, so I free with free()
    if (mode == "NFC") {
        pOutString = utf8proc_NFC(pString);
    } else {
        pOutString = utf8proc_NFD(pString);
    }

    // Converts to a string
    std::string retString = std::string((const char*) pOutString);
    // Frees what was allocated by malloc
    free(pOutString);

    return retString;
}

std::string removeAccents(const std::string &in) {
    std::string decomposedString = calculateUnicodeNormalization(in, "NFD");
    auto pDecomposedString = (const utf8proc_uint8_t*) decomposedString.c_str();

    size_t offset = 0;
    std::string rebuiltString;
    // Iterates through all of the characters, adding to the "offset" each time so the next character can be found
    while (true) {
        utf8proc_int32_t codepoint;

        // This function takes a pointer to a uint8_t array and writes the next unicode character's codepoint into codepoint.
        // The -1 means it reads up to 4 bytes (the max length of a utf-8 character).
        utf8proc_iterate(pDecomposedString + offset, -1, &codepoint);

        // Null terminator, end of string
        if (codepoint == 0) {
            break;
        }

        const utf8proc_int32_t codepointCopy = codepoint;

        utf8proc_uint8_t character;
        // This function takes a codepoint and puts the encoded utf-8 character into "character". It returns the bytes written.
        auto charSize = (size_t) utf8proc_encode_char(codepointCopy, &character);

        // I had been having some problems with trailing random characters (random unicode), but this seemed to fix it.
        // Could that have been related to the error?
        std::string realChar = std::string((const char*) &character).substr(0, charSize);

        // God knows why this is needed, but the above function call seems to somehow alter codepoint
        // Could be to do with the error?
        codepoint = codepointCopy;

        // Increments offset so the next character now would be read
        offset += charSize;

        // The actual useful part of the function: gets the category of the codepoint, and if it is Mark, Nonspacing (and not an iota subscript),
        // does not add it to the rebuilt string
        if ((utf8proc_category(codepoint) == UTF8PROC_CATEGORY_MN) && (codepoint != 0x0345)) {
            continue;
        }

        rebuiltString += realChar;
    }

    // Returns the composed form of the rebuilt string
    return calculateUnicodeNormalization(rebuiltString, "NFC");
}
```

You can test this code, for example, by writing a function main:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << removeAccents("ᾤκεον") << std::endl;
}
```

And expecting a result of "ῳκεον".

I'm not really sure what's going on, and there do not seem to me to be any glaring memory errors (I mean, it seems to work absolutely fine otherwise), but of course, due to my inexperience there may be something I have missed.

Any answers are appreciated, and, as always, if there is anything missing, please comment so I can add it.

Comment: In `removeAccents` you break when `codepoint == 0` I think this will strip the terminating `0` from the string being built.

Comment: @RichardCritten no need to add a terminating null to `std::string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
utf8proc_uint8_t character;
// This function takes a codepoint and puts the encoded utf-8 character into "character". It returns the bytes written.
auto charSize = (size_t) utf8proc_encode_char(codepointCopy, &character);
```

This writes up to 4 bytes into the single byte variable `character` thus corrupting your stack.

```
 std::string((const char*) &character).substr(0, charSize);
```

would be more efficient and less crashy (`&character` isn't a null terminated string) as:

```
 std::string((const char*) &character, charSize);
```

Or even better:

```
 rebuiltString.append((const char*) &character, charSize);
```

Comment: I'll accept straight away when I can! Sorry for being so inexperienced!

Comment: Sorry, I must have made a mistake, even when doing ```utf8proc_uint8_t character[4];

auto charSize = (size_t) utf8proc_encode_char(codepoint, character);```, it still shows the same error. Any pointers?

Comment: @AttoAllas There's probably a similar error elsewhere, you'll have to debug to find the cause, I'm not familiar with utf8proc.

Comment: Thank you so much, memory errors are so haunting having never really had to worry about them before!